# Is there a 3-D alternative for elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves

As I understand the most widely used method to exchange encrypted data over untrusted network is Diffie-Hellman protocol. Protocol itself doesn't define how to encrypt data, but it defines a usage pattern of public/private keys and implementation can vary.

So, original idea was to use big prime numbers (1 number, 1-D) and their combinations as public/private keys. After a while elliptic curves (x and y coordinates, 2-D) was discovered, so now everyone using them.

Do elliptic curves have more cryptographic strength than classical approach because of 2 dimensions? Is there any research related to 3rd (or even more) order polynomial that potentially can provide even more cryptographic strength than elliptic curves?

Comment: Encryption schemes are not based on some vector spaces, but on computationally difficult problems in finite algebraic structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, i've just started to figure out how encryption works.

From what you've said, I fear that's not true.

> As i understand the most widely used method to exchange encrypted data over untrusted network is Diffie-Hellman protocol.

Partially true, as DH is used as key agreement protocol to further derive session **encryption & MAC** key. DH is asymmetric, where as encryption and MAC (message authentication code) are symmetric.

> So, original idea was to use big prime numbers (1 number, 1-D) ... After a while elliptic curves (x and y coordinates, 2-D) was discovered, so now everyone using them.

The original realization of the idea was to use a big prime number, but those numbers that can be represented in binary system have a exploitable structure make possible attacks faster than brutal-force search.

DH is still realized using scalars, except this time, the scalars are points on elliptic curves over finite fields.

> Question is - do elliptic curves have more cryptographic strength than classical approach because of 2 dimensions?

No, they are stronger because they don't have the same exploitable structure as (big) integers.

> Is there researches related to 3-rd (or even more) order polynomes that potentially can provide even more cryptographic strength than elliptic curves?

Yes, one of my questions here attracted [this comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47573/post-quantum-object-sizes#comment107723_47573), but I haven't thoroughly comprehended it, I advise you read it with care if you have time.

Comment: Unrelated: In lattice-based post-quantum cryptography, the lattice used in cryptographic primitives often have high dimensions: 512, 1024, etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLWE-KEX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLWE-SIG.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to set up a hard discrete log problem, we need a cyclic group of order n with a trapdoor isomorphism to $Z_n$.  So we want "weird groups".

Elliptic curves are special algebraic constructions over a field, because they combine, geometrically, and hence algebraically, 3 points: the intersection points with a "straight line" and moreover, they have a two-fold symmetry of their points (mirror symmetry in the x-axis).  This is what makes that they should be quadratic in y (for the symmetry) and third order in x (to have 3 intersection points).

Why do we need 3 points ?  Because a group operation connects a third point (the result) to two given points.  C = A + B.  And why do we need the symmetry ?  To be able to introduce the inverse element: -A that goes with A.
It is the fact that we need an inverse element in a group that is responsible for the $y^2$ ; and it is the fact that a group operation maps a couple of elements to a third one, that makes that we have the $x^3 + ...$ polynomial.

The "miracle" is that this operation is, moreover, associative.

I don't know if there are other algebraic constructions over finite fields that have the same properties, with geometrical constructions in more than 2 dimensions and are not just trivial transformations of elliptic curves.

Comment: Actually, cyclic groups are just a subset of the [finite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_group), which can be used as algebraic structure. Not all elliptic curves over finite groups are cyclic (they can also be the direct product of cyclic groups).

Comment: @tylo: true of course, but a discrete log problem needs a cyclic group as far as I understand.  You're right that elliptic groups aren't necessarily cyclic, but the cryptographic (sub)group used is cyclic, by choice of a (single) generator.

Comment: Well, the DLOG, CDH and DDH problem are defined with a single generator, but that does not mean they are not true outside of this type of construction. Logically speaking, it's an [implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) and not a [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional). The question is asking for constructions beyond the common ones, and key exchange (and public key crypto) do not have to be based on those problems.

Comment: @tylo: I assumed that the question was formulated in the frame of DH, which implies a discrete log problem as far as I understand.  I don't know how you can formulate a discrete log problem outside of a cyclic group, because you are asking for the power of the generator.  How would you even define a discrete logarithm in a group that doesn't have a single generator (isn't cyclic) ? I read the question as what relationship exists between the encryption strength and the dimensionality in which to define a DH key exchange, not about what other ways there could be to establish a common secret.

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful answer. All these crypto-things seem so easy at first sight, but the more i read the less i understand.